# Devise: Custom fallback function for authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to write a function which sets cookie when user is not authenticated. So after authenticate_user! if user is not authenticated the cookie is set. Can this be done in devise.
I tried doing it by customizing authenticate_user! function, but can't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `before_filter` to call `authenticate_user!`? Can't you just do:

```
before_filter do
  authenticate_user!
  your_cookie_method if current_user.nil?
end
```

Comment: I am using it in many engines, so ihave to make these changes in controller of all the engines, which is not good, i want to make change to authenticate_user function of devise